# Cannot call a function from a jQuery on event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="partialViewContainer">
             
<table id="assetTable" class="table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                colulmn1
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-4">
                column2
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-4">
                column3
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-3">
                column4
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   1
                </td>
                <td>
                  2
                </td>
                <td>
                  3
                </td>
                <td>
                   4
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {
       
                  //Get tAble contents
        var getTableContents = function () {
            //Get the reference to the table
            var table = document.getElementById('assetTable');

            //Get the number of rows in the table
            var noOfRows = table.rows.length;

            //Loop through each row of the table
            for (var i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
            //Get the cells of the table
            var cells = table.rows[i].cells;

            //Get the number of cells in each row
            var noOfCells = cells.length;

            for (var j = 0; j < noOfCells; j++) {
                var cellVal = cells.item(j).innerHtml;
                alert(cellVal);
            }
         }
       };

       $('#partialViewContainer').on('click', 'table tr', getTableContents);

       

    });
</script>
```

I am trying to make a call to the function `getTableContents` every time a row is clicked in a table. However with the code pasted above I get an error:

> "Uncaught error: userdefined is not a function."

Anyone got any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work after these two changes:

`function getTableContents() { ... }`

`var cells = table.rows[i].cells;`

If you declare the function after the binding, you need to define it this way.
After it, it complained about `table.rows.items` not being a function. I changed it to `table.rows[i]` and it works.

Comment: yes it did. error was within the function itself. well spotted  thank you danbal

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. Anyway, I used jsfiddle and firebug to spot the bug, it can be useful for you, too, in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because you have not defined the variable "getTableContents" before passing to the "on" method. Move your getTableContents variable declaration above the call to the "on" method and you should be good to go.

Comment: this is true as well however something else within the function was causing the error but well spotted. thank you Michael Nero

Answer (score 2):

try using "function getTableContents(){}" instead.

Comment: i tried that option before. It produces the same error.

Comment: and it says that  getTableContents is not a function? right?
can u make a jsfiddle and post a link

Answer (score 1):

replace the
 $('#partialViewContainer table tr').on...
to

```
$('#partialViewContainer table tr').click(function(){
      getTableContents();
});
```

arguments in js functions are optional.

Comment: it will work Idan but i wanted to  make the function only when the table element is clicked not the container. Thank you for your time

Comment: look at the edit now :)

its pimplier then the others.

Comment: so choose this answer by putting the V next to it. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59016/discussion-between-sike12-and-idan-magled).

Answer (score 1):

Here , you are trying to pass function as a variable name to the callback function on the click event. But before you use the variable, you have to declare it. You are not defining the variable before using it.

Comment: i tried that but it won't work. passing function reference doesnt work in this situation. so the function had to be declared like function a() {} rather than var a= function(){}

Comment: I checked your code. I am getting "has no method item" error. but if i replace it with some other function. it's working fine.           var testing = function(){
   alert('on click');   
  }
       $('#partialViewContainer').on('click', 'table tr', testing);